# Swift error GDTCORAssert.h' file not found during build

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, google-data-api

I'm getting the error every time I try to build:

```
'GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/Internal/GDTCORAssert.h' file not found
```

And this is some extra:

```
1. Did not find header 
'GDTCORLibrary/Internal/GDTCORAssert.h' in framework 'GoogleDataTransport' (loaded from 
'/Users/hubertrzeminski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Skate_App-
armdwqmidyabucctfrwlrpphjudg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport')
```

This keeps happening even though I reverted to a previous commit from git.

Any help would be appreciated.